# Apple App UIPicker - how to make a multiple UIPicker?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I want to make multiple UIPicker with following requirements -

1. Make Multiple UIPicker (let's call them Picker1 and Picker2)
2. Value of Picker2 should automatically change based upon value of Picker1 (for instance I Picker1 has countries and Piker2 should display cities in that country)
3. also I would like to change the data in UIView based upon the value selected from Picker1 and Picker2 (lets say we select "UK" and city as "London" then UIView should talk only about "places to visit in london"

I know it sounds like lot of asking - your help would be highly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on Apple's HIG you may want to use a different data display method such as a UITableView.

Comment: no need to create 2 diffrent UIPicker since it takes your memory. just use the same UIPickerVIew you created, use 'tag' property to make it differ. you will have to change the data to be displayed also. as number 3, i dont quite understand it.

Comment: I agree with Jumhyn. Go to Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> International Keyboards. That's the Apple recommended way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank a lot for your reply.

seems like I have found the exact answer to my question in "Iphone 4 Development.pdf" book in section named "Implementing a Multicomponent Picker", I will impliment the same and will come back. once again many thanks for your reply :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your ViewController(the one with the picker) should implement the UIPickerViewDelegate.
You should than use this method:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

It gets called every time you change a the selected row on any of the components of your picker.
For example when this gets called, you should change the UIView element to the appropriate value.
This is also the moment to reload Component2 (or whatever you want to call it) of your picker like this.

```
[picker reloadComponent:2];
```

or

```
[picker reloadAllComponents];
```

Comment: Thanks Nikola, I will definitely impliment this.